# How to update the variable list for which the optimizer need to update in tensorflow?

Tags: list, variables, optimization, tensorflow

How to update the list of variables for the optimizer to train in tensorflow? In other words, if we have the following optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_scalar, var_list=my_var_list)
```

I need to update my_var_list for example while fine tuning the network. That is, I am going to remove the variable which I no longer need to train and keep the others. Example, fine tuning the dense layer in a convolutional neural network.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

The variable weights and biases will update when you run `optimizer`, with the relevant `feed_dict`, within your session `sess`.

```
for e in range(epoch):
    for i in range(data_size/batch_size):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={your_feed_dict})
```

**EDIT**

You may want to segment your variables and var_list instead, with one that trains the whole network, and one that just trains the dense layer. You can do so by introducing scope to the variables in the convolution layers and dense layers separately

```
with tf.variable_scope("Conv"): #All the convolution layers
    DW0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1], stddev=0.01))
    Db0 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1]))

with tf.variable_scope("Dense"): #All the dense layers
    DW0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1], stddev=0.01))
    Db0 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1]))

vars = tf.trainable_variables()
dense = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith("Dense")]
whole = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith("Conv")] + dense

WholeOptim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_scalar, var_list=whole)
DenseOptim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_scalar, var_list=dense)
```

So when training the whole network, run `WholeOptim` and when training just dense layer, run `DenseOptim`

Comment: This is not what I am looking for @Joshua. For example, if you have a network of 3 convolutional layer followed with 1 dense layer, then after training the whole network, I am going to use the activations of the 3rd conv layer as features for my input frames. Furthermore, I need to train the recurrent neural network only without the conv layers since they are already trained. Hence, in this case, I would like to inform the optimizer to train the weights of the RNN and not the whole network. So this is what I am looking to achieve with the optimizer in tensorflow.